# Defining API path with query string Serverless HTTP API (API Gateway v2)

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-serverless, aws-http-api

How can I define the path in serverless.yml with more than one query parameter using  HTTP API (API Gateway v2)  so that the endpoint looks like the following:

```
https://example.com/rest/endpoint?id=$id&tag=$tag
```

### serverless.yml

```
 dfsPostback: 
    handler:  handlers/result.main 
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /dfs-pingback  // need help here 
          method: get
```

I tried with

```
path: /dfs-pingback?id={id}&tag={tag}
```

deployment failed

Comment: you dont need to specify query strings in the path. however path parameters will need to. they. will be sent in the event object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to specify the query parameters in the path. You should be able to access all passed query params in your event handler.

Comment: I just want to add that, you can read `event.queryStringParameters` (object) containing your params, but if no param is provided then `event.queryStringParameters` (null), so make sure to check type first before destructuring or reading properties.